# Prevent both "modal" opened in same time

Tags: vuejs2

I started to learn VueJS last weekend and some times, simple things can be complex.. I'm sure this is simple but I that vue let this easy.

I have two button which opened modal on click, like this:

```
<el-button class="addOptionBtn" @click="showAddOption = !showAddOption;" :class="{active: showAddOption}">
<el-button class="addGroupBtn" @click="showAddGroup = !showAddGroup;" :class="{active: showAddGroup}">
```

I need to close the opened modal when user click on other. Like a switch.

I tried to create a method who != the value of showAddOption  and showAddOption  but these are not reactively updated in vue data.. Where I do wrong ?

Comment: sounds like you should use a `computed` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I deal with modals, I usually ensure that there is only one.

One way to do that is to use a single variable to track which modal is open

ie: in your vue data

```js
{
  openModal: null,
  // enums, you can use numbers or string or not enumarate at all
  modalEnum: { MODAL_ADD_OPTION: 'option', MODAL_ADD_GROUP: 'group' }
  // ... other data items
}
```

in the template: (also added close to show how to close the modal)

```html
<el-button class="addOptionBtn" @click="openModal = modalEnum.MODAL_ADD_OPTION;" :class="{active: openModal === modalEnum.MODAL_ADD_OPTION}">Option</el-button>
<el-button class="addGroupBtn" @click="openModal = modalEnum.MODAL_ADD_GROUP;" :class="{active: openModal === modalEnum.MODAL_ADD_GROUP}">Group</el-button>

<el-button class="addGroupBtn" @click="openModal = null;" >Close</el-button>
```

then your modal would...

```html
<my-option-modal v-if="openModal === modalEnum.MODAL_ADD_OPTION">...</my-option-modal>
<my-group-modal v-if="openModal === modalEnum.MODAL_ADD_GROUP">...</my-group-modal>
```

This is a slightly simplified version of the implementation, but the basics are there and you can expand on them as needed.